# duplicate pages when pushed with Navigator

Tags: dart, flutter

why pages get duplicated when pushed with Navigator?
I want to switch between pages but always a new instance is created.I don't want to replace or pop ... is there a way to switch pages in Navigator if it is already open in Navigator. we have different routes and we want to switch between pages if it is already in the stack. below is an example to illustrate the issue:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/register');
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/about');
```

Comment: you call `pushNamed` 3 times at a row? what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: @pskink this is an example ... these lines are not one after the other... this was just an example...
for example we are in page "home" after that we go to "register" and then "about"
please read the question again